# AWS DNS Error - SERVFAIL

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, reverse-dns

So I have followed the configuration guide provided by Amazon (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingNewDNS.html),
but I cannot get the URL/Domain to be send out to the name servers.

When I run an nslookup against the IP address it gives no issues, but when I run it against the domain I get:

```
nslookup ttportal.co.uk Server:         
172.31.0.2 Address:       
172.31.0.2#53
** server can't find ttportal.co.uk: SERVFAIL
```

Where could I start looking , I am using the Amazon route 53 to set this up ? I have tried pretty much my limited knowledge told me to.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: One of your sentences appears to be incomplete ("The URL..."), please clarify

Comment: Sorry by URL I mean the domain ttportal.co.uk . So I have added the following to the host zone : ttportal.co.uk.
A
52.17.170.134

Comment: ttportal IN A 52.17.170.134 should be i think in zone co.uk

Answer (score 0):

`ttportal.co.uk` is currently delegated to a set of four name servers (the below according to `nsd.nic.uk` which is one of the servers authoritative for `uk` as well as `co.uk`):

```
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
ttportal.co.uk.         172800  IN      NS      ns-2015.awsdns-59.co.uk.
ttportal.co.uk.         172800  IN      NS      ns-1407.awsdns-47.org.
ttportal.co.uk.         172800  IN      NS      ns-117.awsdns-14.com.
ttportal.co.uk.         172800  IN      NS      ns-679.awsdns-20.net.
```

When querying each of these for the NS records for `ttportal.co.uk` they *all* respond with (for different query IDs, obviously):

```
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 16688
;; flags: qr; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
```

Notice the `REFUSED` part. Since based on this your resolver (at 172.31.0.2) is unable to get an authoritative answer from any of the delegated servers, it bails out and returns a `SERVFAIL` response to the client (you). This is then further presented by most clients as "could not find the host name" or similar.

It would appear that **something is causing the AWS DNS servers to refuse queries from the Internet for your domain.** I'm not familiar with Amazon's offerings, but assuming that the zone itself is properly configured, it seems plausible that there are some **security settings** that need to be checked and possibly adjusted.

Comment: There aren't any security settings in Route 53 (other than making a hosted zone *completely* private to your own VPC, which isn't easy to do "accidentally") but each hosted zone in any account has a unique-ish combination of auto-assigned x and y for ns-xxxx.awsdns-yy.tld (no two domains are ever supposed to have more than 2 in common, for resiliency, iirc).  Deleting a zone and putting it back again (an unnecessary but probably common blind troubleshooting tactic) changes these values, requiring a change to the root servers so queries go to the right clusters.

Comment: Thanks. I deleted it to avoid the cost involved with running a host zone on amazon when it was not needed. So the  ns-xxxx.awsdns-yy.tld did definitely change from the first one to the one I created now. How does one go about making a change to the root servers so queries go to the right cluster?